# Print screen software to capture subsequent screens

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, print-screen

i am looking for a print screen software which will capture subsequent screens/frames
then save them all at the end.

**requirement**: i have a movie and i want to capture subsequent frames of a scene.
please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SnagIt from TechSmith at http://www.techsmith.com/snagit-features.html has a capture timer.  You can set an interval of 1 second or more and it will save each capture as it goes.  Many choices of file format.  SnagIt will capture a window, a defined region, and any of many other options.  It's very feature rich but not cheap.  There is a 30 day free trail but the permananet license costs $50.

Comment: SangIt is excellent software for this. The $50 license is a steal once you realize how useful this program is. I use it all the time at home and work! And I don't work for the developer either ;)

Answer (score 1):

**For Screen Shots**

Try VLC Media player From [VideoLan](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)

Instructions

How can I take screenshots?

To take a snapshot of the video displayed by VLC, you just need to press the pre-defined snapshot hotkey:
Windows / Linux / Unix: Ctrl+Alt+S
Mac OS X: Command+Alt+s
To change it, go to Preferences -> Interface -> Hotkeys settings, check Advanced options, and set Take video snapshot.
You can also take a snaphot via the menu Video -> Snapshot.
To change the snapshot format or directory, go to Preferences -> Video.

Source:[Video Lan FAQs](http://www.videolan.org/support/faq.html)

**For Video Clips**
Try [AVS Video Converter](http://www.avs4you.com/AVS-Video-Converter.aspx)